# Pharmacokinetics and cell-membrane permeability of Adenosine triphosphate disodium hydrate

Tags: cell-biology, brain, pharmacology, cell-membrane, cell-culture

**【My Question】**
**(1)** Please tell me the pharmacokinetics of this ATP (or Adenosine triphosphate disodium hydrate) when it is administered orally or intravenously. In particular, Does this material has permeability to the Blood-Brain Barrier?
**(2)** When human cells (for example, fibroblast, MSC,…,) are cultured in a medium supplemented with this material, how much ATP is taken into the cells. (Please tell me about the cell-membrane permeability of this material.)

The known effects of Adenosine triphosphate disodium hydrate are as described below.

**【Effects of this medicine】**
This medicine increases the blood flow by its vasodilatory effect and activates the metabolism of the body to improves the functions of the organs.
It is usually used to improve symptoms accompanied by aftereffects from head injury; to treat heart failure or chronic gastritis associated with dysfunction of the digestive tract, Meniere's disease, dizziness based on inner ear disorder; to stabilize the accommodative function in accommodative asthenopia.

**【References】**
http://www.rad-ar.or.jp/siori/english/kekka.cgi?n=1808#

P.S.
P.S. I'm not very good at English, so I'm sorry if I have some impolite or unclear expressions. I welcome any corrections and English review. (You can edit my question and description to improve them)